# R markdown, params with vector

Tags: r

i would like to create a script in R with params, can I create a params as vector?
For example:
I have this command:  mutate(cluster=case_when((offert=="xxx" & prod %in% c("a","b") & year==params$year1 & month %in% **c(2,3,4,5)**) ~"Cluster1")
I would like to replace c(2,3,4,5) with params$months , but if i set params with months: c(2,3,4,5) it doesn't work, cluster is NA.
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, not sure I fully understand, here's my minimal example using a vector parameter which works about as I'd expect:

````
---
title: "test.Rmd"
output: html_document
params:
  a: !r c(1, 2, 4)
---

``` {r, echo = FALSE}
# output params
params$a

# test if value "1" is in params (expect TRUE)
if (1 %in% params$a) {
  "True"
} else {
  "False"
}

# test if value "3" is in params (expect FALSE)
if (3 %in% params$a) {
  "True"
} else {
  "False"
}
```
````